# Elastic with Kibana on docker gives Kibana server is not ready yet

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana

I have Elastic & Kibana and suddenly last week it stopped working with the error `Kibana server is not ready yet`. I have seen numerous threads on gooogle about this problem. Tried it all with no luck at all.
I can see in the kibana logs the following errors:

```
License information could not be obtained from Elasticsearch due to Error: Error: certificate has expired error"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-31T13:45:24Z","tags":["info","monitoring","kibana-monitoring"],"pid":6,"message":"Monitoring status upload endpoint is not enabled in Elasticsearch:Monitoring stats collection is stopped"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-31T13:45:54Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":6,"message":"Request error, retrying\nGET https://el.mydomain.io:9200/_xpack => certificate has expired"}
```

I checked the certificate. It is not expired. It expires next February.
Any idea what is happening?

Update #1: Added docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.2'

services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${VERSION}
    container_name: el.mydomain.io
    environment:
      - node.name=el.mydomain.io
      - discovery.type=single-node       
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"      
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=trial # <1>
      - xpack.security.enabled=true      
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true # <2>
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true # <3>
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate # <4>
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.key
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes: 
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - /home/user11/SSL-Certs/:$CERTS_DIR
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic

    healthcheck:
      test: curl --cacert $CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt -s https://el.mydomain.io:9200 >/dev/null; if [[ $$? == 52 ]]; then echo 0; else echo 1; fi
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  kib01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:${VERSION}
    container_name: kib.mydomain.io
    depends_on: {"es01": {"condition": "service_healthy"}}
    ports:
      - 443:5601    
    environment:
      SERVERNAME: kib.mydomain.io
      SERVER.HOST: kib.mydomain.io
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: https://el.mydomain.io:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: https://el.mydomain.io:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME: kibana
      ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD: Mypassword
      ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_CERTIFICATEAUTHORITIES: $CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      SERVER_SSL_ENABLED: "true"
      SERVER_SSL_KEY: $CERTS_DIR/kib01/kib01.key
      SERVER_SSL_CERTIFICATE: $CERTS_DIR/kib01/kib01.crt
    volumes: 
      - /home/user11/SSL-Certs/:$CERTS_DIR
    networks:
      - elastic    
volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local
    #certs:
    #driver: local

networks: 
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

Update #2:
Output from certificates:

```
C:\Temp>openssl verify -CAfile ca.crt es01.crt
C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
error 10 at 3 depth lookup: certificate has expired
C = US, ST = New Jersey, L = Jersey City, O = The USERTRUST Network, CN = USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
error 10 at 2 depth lookup: certificate has expired
error es01.crt: verification failed

C:\Temp>openssl verify -CAfile ca.crt kib01.crt
C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
error 10 at 3 depth lookup: certificate has expired
C = US, ST = New Jersey, L = Jersey City, O = The USERTRUST Network, CN = USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
error 10 at 2 depth lookup: certificate has expired
error kib01.crt: verification failed

C:\Temp>openssl x509 -noout -in es01.crt -dates
notBefore=Jan  2 00:00:00 2020 GMT
notAfter=Jan  1 23:59:59 2021 GMT

C:\Temp>openssl x509 -noout -in kib01.crt -dates
notBefore=Jan  2 00:00:00 2020 GMT
notAfter=Jan  1 23:59:59 2021 GMT

C:\Temp>openssl x509 -noout -in ca.crt -dates
notBefore=Nov  2 00:00:00 2018 GMT
notAfter=Dec 31 23:59:59 2030 GMT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a license issue, but your SSL certificate has expired. The error message states

> Request error, retrying\nGET https://el.mydomain.io:9200/_xpack => certificate has expired

So you simply need to [renew your certificate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.7/configuring-tls.html#node-certificates)

Comment: I just downloaded from the machine that hosts elastic and kibana. The certificates expire on 02/01/2021. Even if I visit https://el.mydomain.com with chrome I can see that certificate is valid

Comment: We're talking about the ES node certificate, right? not the host, www or whatever certificate, correct? Can you share your elasticsearch.yml and kibana.yml config files?

Comment: Thanks! What do you get when running `openssl verify -CAfile ca.crt es01.crt` and `openssl verify -CAfile ca.crt kib01.crt`?

Comment: Can you update your question with the properly formatted output for both certificates please?

Comment: Updated If I double click the es01.crt in windows explorer it says ```Valid from: 02/01/2020 to 02/01/2021```

Comment: I don't see the output in your question

Comment: And can you also run this `openssl x509 -noout -in es01.crt -dates` and `openssl x509 -noout -in kib01.crt -dates` ?

Comment: Interesting. What about `openssl x509 -noout -in ca.crt -dates` ? It might be the CA that is expired

Comment: Updated with the ca.crt

Comment: Ok, interesting to see that `openssl verify` yields `certificate has expired` for both certs too, there must be one certificate in the chain that is expired

Comment: One of the three (ca.crt, es01, kib01.crt) you mean?

Comment: No I mean in the certificate chain `ca.crt -> es01.crt` there must be an intermediate certificate that is not valid anymore

Comment: But if any of the certificate in the chain was not valid anymore then why when I open the https://el.mydomain.io in browser I dont get any errors?

Comment: The browser only connects to port 443 (Kibana) of el.mydomain.io which probably serves a different certificate than port 9200 (ES). Have you tried connecting to el.mydomain.io:9200 through your browser?

Comment: They use the same certificate (443 and 9200) Check the yml file. I just checked https://el.mydomain.io:9200 and certificate is valid

Comment: 443 is where kibana listens and it uses `kib01.crt` while 9200 uses `es01.crt`

Comment: Correct but technicaly it is the same wildcard certificate

Comment: Dumb question but can you make sure that your container is properly synced with an NTP server? What's the current date/time of the container?

Comment: the openssl commands that you sent me to run was ran in another computer. I checked the dates on both containers they are correct

Comment: just wanted to let you know that you were right. This was a certificate problem. CA chain was expired. Just replaced with the new CA bundle and voila. Elastic is back. Thanks for all the help

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback. Fantastic, glad you finally figured it out!!!

Answer (score 1):

looking at this part of your error message

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-31T13:45:54Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":6,"message":"Request error, retrying\nGET https://el.mydomain.io:9200/_xpack => certificate has expired"}
```

Looks like your x-pack license expired which might be causing the issue, can you please fix this issue or remove the x-pack and try again.

Comment: The certificate has expired, which is different from the license

Comment: I just downloaded from the machine that hosts elastic and kibana. The certificates expire on 02/01/2021. Even if I visit https://el.mydomain.com with chrome I can see that certificate is valid

Comment: We're talking about the ES node certificate, right? not the host or www certificate

Comment: @Val sorry I dont have much idea about this, just saw this as error and thought of pointing it out as a potential cause, what you think can this stop the connection b.w kibana and es?

Comment: @Val sorry I dont have much idea about this, just saw this as error and thought of pointing it out as a potential cause, what you think can this stop the connection b.w kibana and es?

Comment: I was just answering to pantonis' comment. His ES node certificate has expired and he needs to generate a new one